# How to PHPDoc arguments of anonymous functions?

Tags: php, phpdoc

For example, in my Laravel code, I have:

```
$query = User::select('ID', 'Name')
    ->with(['agent' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('MemberID', 'dbPhoto');
    }])->get();
```

Without type hinting $query, my ide will issue a warning of the unknown method select().

If I don't want to type hint $query, as it may accept different types (but not in this case), how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think that type hinting is the best way to solve your problem.

Time ago i saw this [thread](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/1712) in phpDoc's github. Bielive that we still don't have any standart for this.

You can also add some rules to your IDE's types analyzer. Or try to use some ugly hack like below

```
$query = User::select('ID', 'Name')
    ->with(['agent' => function ($query) {
        /** @var \Ns\Query $query */
        $query->select('MemberID', 'dbPhoto');
    }])->get();
```

Do not know will it works in your IDE, but it works in my phpStorm.

Comment: Yes. I tried that before and it does work, but it’s unbelievably ugly to me... I’ll probably try to type hint this...